# CTRL+V does not work in Firefox

Tags: firefox, text-editors, clipboard

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> is not working in FireFox 29. I have included clipboard settings in `about:config`, but it still is not working. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> are both working. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: 7 years is a long time but I am facing this exact problem although on Firefox on MacOS. Do you remember how and if you resolved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently with what was the latest stable version of FF at the time (31 I think but could be wrong), safemode etc made no difference, but updating to the beta channel resolved for me.

So could either try that, a reinstall, or a profile reset.